# I am trying to move to selenium java to ruby but finding the learning curve much tougher

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, eclipse, selenium

I have used Selenium Webdriver in Java for a longtime. I am trying to move to selenium webdriver & ruby but finding the learning process much tougher as the IDE i use for ruby is not as supportive as Eclipse. 
Please suggest utilities or methods that help in understanding the Selenium Ruby syntax and options/features quickly

Comment: You can use eclipse by getting the ruby libraries from Market place ..

Comment: http://assertselenium.com/2013/10/06/getting-started-with-ruby-webdriver/   this may helps you. And regarding IDE.. Try Sublime or RubyMine

Comment: @SaiVardhan Thanks for your suggestion. I am not able to see selenium specific options and syntax suggestions in eclipse.Should i point my eclipse to my gem repository

Comment: Personally, I find that RSpec, Capybara, Poltergeist and PhantomJS make for a lovely stack for end-to-end testing. Between RSpec and Capybara you have a nice high-level of abstraction for writing your tests. Poltergeist and PhantomJS team up to enable headless testing w/o a browser rendering pages (yet screen capture is still possible). Believe the selenium driver is the default for Capybara as well. See https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara

Comment: @unigeek Thanks for suggestion. I am using eclipse with DLTK plugin for ruby development. If i install capybara gem, will get code assistance/ auto suggestion in the editor

Comment: Am not familiar with the DLTK Ruby plugin, but it seems like a tough problem to support API assistance for a dynamic language like Ruby, so I doubt you'd have it after adding RSpec and Capybara. That said, by using RSpec and Capybara you get a nice small DSL for testing so that the lack of API assistance becomes less of an issue.